# While loop goes on forever

Tags: while-loop, sybase

I wanted to create a while loop in sybase that loops while there is any entry left in my temporary table "nodesNotHavingCriteria".
But the procedure i created below seems to go on forever and I think this is because the while loop is going on an don but I dnt seem to find reason for it.
Can anyone help? It seems fine to me and unable to find the reason of never ending loop.

```
 create PROCEDURE createCriteria
    as begin 
    declare @uid varchar(10)
    while (select count(*) from #nodesNotHavingCriteria) > 0
      set rowcount 1
      select @uid = nodes from #nodesNotHavingCriteria -- pull one uid from the temp table
      set rowcount 0
      delete from #nodesNotHavingCriteria where nodes = @uid -- delete that uid from the temp table

      -- Do something with the uid you have
      --insert into BacktestingCriteria (nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
    --  (@uid,16008,16,3)
    --insert into BacktestingCriteria (nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
      --(@uid,16008,16,4)
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your while loop is not check criteria ever again. It select count just only once and check > 0 forever

Maybe you should try something like (pseudo code in js)

```
var count = select count(*) from #nodesNotHavingCriteria;
while(count > 0)
    // Do anything
    count = select count(*) from #nodesNotHavingCriteria;
```

Also I don't know about sybase but is the #nodesNotHavingCriteria really update after you delete from it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.
I should have added begin after while.This works

```
  create PROCEDURE createCriteria
as begin 
declare @uid varchar(10)
while ((select count(*) from #nodesNotHavingCriteria)>0)
begin
  set rowcount 1
  select @uid = nodes from #nodesNotHavingCriteria -- pull one uid from the temp table
  set rowcount 0
  delete from #nodesNotHavingCriteria where nodes = @uid -- delete that uid from the temp table

  -- Do something with the uid you have
  insert into BacktestingCriteria (nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
 (@uid,16008,16,3)
insert into BacktestingCriteria (nodeId,hierarchyViewId,varCriteriaId,pnlCriteriaId) values
  (@uid,16008,16,4)
end
end
```